# Test connect DHCP Kea / ISC DHCPDISCOVER PACKET_NAK_0001

Tags: json, debian, dhcp

The DHCP server is on a different network. I lifted the virtual machine Linux, there are two interfaces. Error DHCPDISCOVER PACKET_NAK_0001.

On a Linux virtual machine, I execute the commands:

```
dhcrelay ip_dhcp -i name_interface

dhclient -v name_interface -s ip_dhcp
```

An example of a config which I send through "curl":

```
{
"command": "config-set",
"service": [
    "dhcp4"
],
"arguments": {
"Dhcp4": {
    "option-def": [
        {
            "name": "configRevision",
            "code": 254,
            "type": "string",
            "space": "dhcp4"
        }
    ],
    "interfaces-config": {
        "interfaces": [
            "*"
        ],
        "dhcp-socket-type": "udp"
    },
    "control-socket": {
        "socket-type": "unix",
        "socket-name": "/tmp/kea-dhcp4-ctrl.sock"
    },
    "lease-database": {
        "type": "postgresql",
        "host": "host",
        "name": "name",
        "user": "name",
        "password": "pass",
        "port": 5432,
        "lfc-interval": 600
    },
    "expired-leases-processing": {
        "reclaim-timer-wait-time": 10,
        "flush-reclaimed-timer-wait-time": 25,
        "hold-reclaimed-time": 3600,
        "max-reclaim-leases": 100,
        "max-reclaim-time": 250,
        "unwarned-reclaim-cycles": 5
    },
    "valid-lifetime": 3600,
    "authoritative": true,
    "hooks-libraries": [
        {
            "library": "/usr/local/lib/hooks/libdhcp_lease_cmds.so"
        },
        {
            "library": "/usr/local/lib/hooks/libdhcp_stat_cmds.so"
        }
    ],
    "option-data": [
        {
            "name": "configRevision",
            "code": 254,
            "data": "1",
            "always-send": false
        },
        {
            "name": "domain-name-servers",
            "data": "<IP>, <IP>",
            "always-send": true
        },
        {
            "name": "time-servers",
            "data": "<IP>",
            "always-send": true
        },
        {
            "name": "ntp-servers",
            "data": "<IP>",
            "always-send": true
        },
        {
            "name": "domain-name",
            "data": "<DOMAIN>",
            "always-send": true
        },
        {
            "name": "dhcp-server-identifier",
            "data": "<IP>"
        }
    ],
    "shared-networks": [
        {
            "name": "Zone 1",
            "relay": {
                "ip-addresses": [
                    "172.100.100.100",
                    "<IP>",
                    "<IP>",
                    "<IP>"
                ]
            },
            "option-data": [],
            "subnet4": [
                {
                    "id": 1314,
                    "subnet": "172.100.100.99/23",
                    "option-data": [
                        {
                            "name": "routers",
                            "data": "172.100.100.100"
                        }
                    ],
                    "pools": [
                        {
                            "pool": "172.100.100.130-172.100.100.254",
                            "client-class": "UNKNOWN"
                        }
                    ],
                    "valid-lifetime": 86400,
                    "reservations": []
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Expected Result:
Successful issuance of IP address.

Actual result:
ERROR [kea-dhcp4.bad-packets/26218] DHCP4_PACKET_NAK_0001 [hwtype=1 
], cid=[no info], tid=0x23acf436: failed to select a subnet for 
incoming packet, src 172.100.100.100, type DHCPDISCOVER

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A stack trace alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies with client-class, not being known in time for subnet selection. Viz [Kea Docs](https://kea.readthedocs.io/en/kea-1.6.3/arm/dhcp4-srv.html#dhcpv4-server-configuration)

> The determination whether there is a reservation for a given client is made after a subnet is selected, so it is not possible to use “KNOWN”/”UNKNOWN” classes to select a shared network or a subnet.